# How can I apply imgaug augmentation to a tensorflow dataset created with dataset_from_directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, image-augmentation

I'm curently trying to apply some data augmentation using imgaug to my existing trainDataset.

The dataset is created using dataset_from_directory as shown below.

```
trainDataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    class_names=classNames,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=seed,
    validation_split=0.15,
    subset='training',
    interpolation='bilinear',
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)
```

The imgaug I'm trying to apply to the dataset is shown below

```
augmenter = iaa.Sequential([
    iaa.Fliplr(0.5),
    iaa.Affine(rotate=(-10, 10)),
    iaa.Affine(scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)}),
    iaa.Crop(percent=(0, 0.1)),
    iaa.Sometimes(0.5, iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 0.5))),
    iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(loc=0, scale=(0.0, 0.05*255), per_channel=0.5),
    iaa.Multiply((0.8, 1.2), per_channel=0.2),
    iaa.AddToHueAndSaturation((-20, 20))
])
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to actually apply this to my dataset. I've tried using map but it doesn't work as the augmenter is expecting a numpy array? Any help would be appreciated :)

p.s this is my first time posting so apologies if I've left out anything important

## Update 1:

I've now changed my code a bit so the dataset isn't being split before applying any augmentation and changed around some stuff that was recommended to me.

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='int',
    class_names=classNames,
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=64,
    image_size=(224, 224),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=seed,
    interpolation='bilinear',
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)

augmenter = iaa.Sequential([
    iaa.Fliplr(0.5),
    iaa.Affine(rotate=(-10, 10)),
    iaa.Affine(scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)}),
    iaa.Crop(percent=(0, 0.1)),
    iaa.Sometimes(0.5, iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0, 0.5))),
    iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(loc=0, scale=(0.0, 0.05*255), per_channel=0.5),
    iaa.Multiply((0.8, 1.2), per_channel=0.2),
    iaa.AddToHueAndSaturation((-20, 20))
])

def augment(image, label):
    image = tfds.as_numpy(image)
    image = augmenter.augment_image(image)
    image = tf.convert_to_tensor(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    return image, label

augDataset = dataset.map(augment)
```

I'm now getting the following error and have no clue what it means.

You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'args_0' with dtype float and shape [?,224,224,3][[{{node args_0}}]]

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using older `TensorFlow` version code along with few deprecated augmentation API's.

You can use Image preprocessing or Image data augmentation [layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers) for the [augmentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation). These layers can be defined inside the model after fetching the dataset using `image_dataset_from_directory` as below:

```
classifier = tf.keras.Sequential([

##data augmention layers    
  layers.Resizing(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE),
  layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  layers.RandomFlip("horizontal"),
  layers.RandomZoom(0.1),
  
#model building layers
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3), activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
  layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation = 'relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu'),
  layers.Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
```

Please refer this [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/04905491613cc38ed97e505b0c20082f/75201316.ipynb#scrollTo=AqSMDyIt1KzW) for your reference.